# Degree of Quantum Entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer

I am a bit confused about the definition of "degree of quantum entanglement". 
1- Could anyone give me a generic definition for that?

Moreover, it is not intuitive for me the strategy by which we can figure the most entangled superposition through all possible states. For example, in 2-d Hilbert space, the most entangled state in 2-qubit Dirac notation is:

```
0.5^0.5 |00> + 0.5^0.5 |11>
```

2- My question is why this state is the one?

3- What is the reason that we can figure most entangled state for 2-D system but it is not doable for larger systems?

Thanks!

Comment: it would be better if you could ask a single question per post. Also, note that you can use mathjax to render math on the site

Comment: what's your definition of "degree of quantum entanglement"?

Comment: So I can define it intuitively as 'the more entangled the states are, the more exact the result of the measurement would be (you can consider measurement's result as spin up/down)'

Comment: but you are asking for a "more generic definition than that". What is the definition what you encountered? The one you mention is not a definition.